# trying to learn _beginthreadex and passing parameters

Tags: multithreading, parameters

copying some data I had for working boost threads, I implemented the following code below.
I get the error C:\dev\default threads_threads.cpp|18|error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(void*)' to 'unsigned int (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) *)(void*)' [-fpermissive]|

but... the commented lines are what was recommended, and a comment explains the error I got.

it turns out _beginThreadEx is highly recommended, but poorly documented (as in tutorials) on the web

```
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

void myThread(void *data)
{
    //C:\dev\default threads\_threads.cpp|6|error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
    //int x = static_cast<int*>(data);

    int *x = (int*)data;

    std::cout << "Hellow World! " << x;
}

int main()
{

    int x = 10;
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, myThread, &x, 0, NULL);
    while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare x as pointer anyway:

```
int *x = static_cast<int*>(data);
```

both `_beginthread` and `_beginthreadex` are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.80).aspx

According to the declaration of _beginthreadex() your myThread() function should be declared like this:

```
unsigned __stdcall myThread(void *data);
```

Comment: I read that somewhere on how the function should be defined, and was surprised to see someone elses recommendation on how it should go.  thanks... will try.... got it working, missed a * ...int *x = static_cast<int*>(data);